# Why does self injection with CDI not result in an infinite loop?

Tags: jakarta-ee, cdi

Why this construction works?

```
@Stateless
public class SomeClass {

    @Inject
    private SomeClass self;

    //...
}
```

Why is there no infinite recursion of object reference injecting?
When does the container realize it's time to stop?

Comment: I think because the Injection is done in the moment your self-variable is used the first time.

Comment: I don't think it needs to realise anything; "self" will literally be the exact same EJB instance. It gets created once, it gets injected once. You could verify that by setting a debugger breakpoint somewhere and checking the object IDs to see if they are the same.

Comment: @Gimby, not necessarily. E.g. Wildfly pools Stateless beans by default, but that's not required by Java EE - they can be different instances.

Comment: @VsevolodGolovanov yeah please don't respond to old comments.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In addition to the Petr's great answer, one of the core concepts of CDI is that you are actually injecting *Proxies*, not actual objects. When you invoke a function on the proxy, you are routed to the correct bean instance in the container. This allows self-injection to work, as well as other scenarios like Injecting a RequestScoped bean into an ApplicationScoped (how would this work if the container was injecting actual instances?)

Answer (score 3):

In this particular case you are self-injecting stateless EJB. In case of Wildfly, `@Stateless` has no correlation to any of CDI scopes, so your bean ends as `@Dependent` (discussion whether it’s correct or not can be found here https://issues.redhat.com/browse/CDI-414). So, in case of Wildfly it ends with error "WELD-001443: Pseudo scoped bean has circular dependencies".

CDI currently supports circular dependency (in your case self-injecting) when one of the beans (in your case same bean) has normal scope: `@RequestScoped,` `@SessionScoped`, `@ApplicationScoped`, `@ConversationScoped`.

So `@Dependent` as pseudo-scope will end in WELD-001443, but other scopes works because framework uses client proxy (if you log `@Inject` variable you can see that toString() will print info about proxy object). After method is called on this proxy CDI framework does contextual lookup, and this is the reason why no infinite loop happens during initialization of this bean.

For `@Dependent`, no proxy is used, and direct reference is created. This is purpose of WELD-001443, to protect you from infinite loop.